# Error converting data type nvarchar to float with Sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get this error Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

When I try running this query...

```
select 
  * 
from 
  products.products
order by 
  case 
      when len(PartNumber) < 3 then ''
      else substring(PartNumber,1,3)
  end,
  case 
      when len(PartNumber) < 4 then ''
      when isnumeric(substring(PartNumber,4,len(PartNumber) - 4)) = 1 then
      cast(substring(PartNumber,4,len(PartNumber) - 4) as float)
      else ''
  end
go
```

PartNumber is nvarchar(50)

And I can't change it to as nvarchar because then it doesn't sort correctly....

Thank you.  I have been trying to fix this forever.

Comment: Well, for starters, the result of your `CASE` expression should have one datatype, but you are currently either returning `''` (which is a string) and a `FLOAT`

Comment: Show us some example part numbers and tell us how you want them sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lamak said, your `CASE` statement needs to have a single data type. You can't use an empty string, but fortunately you can use `Null`.

```
select 
  * 
from 
  products.products
order by 
  case 
      when len(PartNumber) < 3 then ''
      else substring(PartNumber,1,3)
  end,
  case 
      when len(PartNumber) < 4 then Null
      when isnumeric(substring(PartNumber,4,len(PartNumber) - 4)) = 1 then
      cast(substring(PartNumber,4,len(PartNumber) - 4) as float)
      else Null
  end
```

You should also beware of the `IsNumeric` function - there are many cases when it returns `1` but the string cannot be converted to a number.

Answer (score 0):

another way to go is by doing it in steps. This way you can easily finetune which results comes first or last. 
But here also counts what @Richard said. For example: select isnumeric(",123") gives 1 but don't try to cast it to a float!
Secondly you might want to check you substrings.

```
select substring('12,34',4,len('12,34') - 4)
```

doesn't give '34' or '4' but '3'. I'm not sure what you are expecting here but be aware of this.

my resultquery:

```
select products.*
  ,
  case when (len(PartNumber) >= 4) AND isnumeric(substring(PartNumber,4,len(PartNumber) - 4)) = 1
      then substring(PartNumber,4,len(PartNumber) - 4)
      else '0'
  end
from 
  products
order by 
  case 
      when len(PartNumber) < 3 then ''
      else substring(PartNumber,1,3)
  end,
  case 
      when len(PartNumber) < 4 then 1
      else 0
  end,
  case when (len(PartNumber) >= 4) AND isnumeric(substring(PartNumber,4,len(PartNumber) - 4)) = 1 
    then 1
    else 0
  end,
  case when (len(PartNumber) >= 4) AND isnumeric(substring(PartNumber,4,len(PartNumber) - 4)) = 1
      then substring(PartNumber,4,len(PartNumber) - 4)
      else '0'
  end
go
```

if you want to play some more with my query, here is my sqlfiddle link:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80b2e/3